# Retrofit Success call

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I am learning android and know basic editing etc. I have one application which have developed by one freelancer. We are using Retrofit 2.0 for do some task in it. One of my function is like below

```
private void serverCall() {
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(WithdrawActivity.this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.show();


    HashMap<String, String> payload = new HashMap<>();
    String uid = settings.getString("userid", "");
    payload.put("UID", uid);
    payload.put("Name", etName.getText().toString().trim());
    payload.put("MobileNumber", etPaytmMobileNumber.getText().toString().trim());
    payload.put("Amount", etAmount.getText().toString().trim());

    //  NetworkApiInterface apiClient = NetworkApiClient.getClient().create(NetworkApiInterface.class);
    NetworkApiInterface apiClient = retrofit.create(NetworkApiInterface.class);
    Call<WithdrawalCreditResponseModel> call = apiClient.withdrawalCredit(payload);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<WithdrawalCreditResponseModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<WithdrawalCreditResponseModel> call, Response<WithdrawalCreditResponseModel> response) {
            if (response != null) {
                WithdrawalCreditResponseModel responseModel = response.body();
                if (responseModel != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, new Gson().toJson(responseModel));
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(responseModel.getMsg())) {
                        Toast.makeText(WithdrawActivity.this, responseModel.getMsg(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    if (responseModel.isSuccess()) {
                        setResult(RESULT_OK);
                        finish();
                        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (progressDialog != null) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<WithdrawalCreditResponseModel> call, Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, t.getCause() + "");
            if (progressDialog != null) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

I want show toast when call is success. I have tried to put it in many place but its not showing. I have tried to put it after this line etc

```
if (responseModel.isSuccess()) {
                        setResult(RESULT_OK);
                        Toast.makeText(WithdrawActivity.this, "This Toast Need toShow.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        finish();
                        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
                    }
```

This is response model

```
public class WithdrawalCreditResponseModel implements Serializable {

@SerializedName("msg")
@Expose
private String msg;
@SerializedName("success")
@Expose
private boolean success;

public String getMsg() {
    return msg;
}

public void setMsg(String msg) {
    this.msg = msg;
}

public boolean isSuccess() {
    return success;
}

public void setSuccess(boolean success) {
    this.success = success;
}
```

}

But its not showing anything. However my task is going completed without any issue. Can somebody please check and tell me what is issue in it ?

Thanks

Comment: post your response

Comment: Try to comment out code setResult(RESULT_OK); and finish();
                        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);. Check if toast is visible. If yes then place Toast.makeText above setResult...

Comment: The reason your toast is not shown is because the activity finishes as soon as the request is completed. If you want to see the toast comment then out the other 3 lines.

Comment: @RajeshPanchal I have added response. Thanks

Comment: @akash93 I have tried it...but no luck

Comment: @AnuragSingh I have already tried it but its not working as well not giving any errors

Comment: I said response, response which you're getting from server

Comment: Check in your server response if the `success` parameter is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're getting success as a true and it's in boolean because in your model class you've taken success as a boolean

Comment: Thanks...there was issue in server side because we was not getting success message true from it. Now it has been fixed...there no any issue in above code. Thanks